# Errors when signing a Windows 10 Universal Platform application (with signtool)

Tags: java, uwp, signature, pfx, signtool

I'm trying to sign an .appx file made converting a java application following this [github guide](https://github.com/crramirez/uwp_bridge_java)

I ended up with having the `.appx` package
I tryied to sign it with the project's certificates and it gives error

```
signtool.exe /a /f auto-generated.pfx /p 123456 swingset.appx
```

it throws

> SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given
> criteria.

then I tried to make a certificate using windows's tools:

```
MakeCert /n "CN=MyCo" /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e 12/31/2050 /sv MyKey2.pvk MyKey2.cer
rem then creating a pfx
Pvk2Pfx /pvk MyKey.pvk /pi 123456 /spc MyKey.cer /pfx mykey.pfx /po 123456
```

then

```
signtool.exe sign /a /f mykey.pfx /p 123456 swingset.appx
```

resulting in:

> Done Adding Additional Store SignTool Error: An unexpected internal
> error has occurred. Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed."
> (-2146889723/0x80091005)

I also tried to make my own certificates using OpenSSL using the following code:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.key -out certificate.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt

signtool.exe sign /a /f certificate.pfx /p 123456 swingset.appx
```

resulting in the same error:

> Done Adding Additional Store SignTool Error: An unexpected internal
> error has occurred. Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed."
> (-2146889723/0x80091005)

How can I fix it?

Comment: By any chance should your file extension be `.appxbundle`?

Comment: How can I make it using the makeappx.exe tool (I'm not on Visual Studio)

Comment: I mean try renaming the `.appx` file to `.appxbundle` and see if that fixes it. If you have the extension wrong, it won't sign. Just a thought.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you